# Issue with scraping LinkedIn Ads Library

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape LinkedIn Ads Library(eg. https://www.linkedin.com/ad-library/search?accountOwner=salesforce&dateOption=last-30-days).

While scraping with beautiful soup, the image tags return:

which do not contain the src tag. I need to scrape the src tags along with the tags and content from the ads.

This is my code for reference:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def LinkedInAdScraper(company: str):
url = f"https://www.linkedin.com/ad-library/search?accountOwner={company}&dateOption=last-30-days"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Find all instances of ad previews
    ad_previews = soup.find_all('div', class_='base-ad-preview-card')

    for ad_preview in ad_previews:
        # Extracting image link, title, and content for each ad preview
        image_tag = ad_preview.select_one('.ad-preview__dynamic-dimensions-image')
        # Check if 'data-ghost-url' attribute is present, if yes, use it, otherwise fall back to 'src'
        image_link = image_tag.get('data-ghost-url') or image_tag.get('src')
        title = ad_preview.select_one('.text-md').text.strip() if ad_preview.select_one('.text-md') else None
        content = ad_preview.select_one('.commentary__content').text.strip() if ad_preview.select_one('.commentary__content') else None

        print("Image Link:", image_link)
        print("Title:", title)
        print("Content:", content)


         print("-" * 50)

    else:
        print("Failed to retrieve the page. Status code:", response.status_code)

LinkedInAdScraper("SalesForce")
```

I'm open to other methods to scrape the LinkedIn images for each ads if there are any.

Comment: be careful seems like imgs are lazily loaded from this cdn https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/ in batches of ~30 which refreshes when you scroll all the way down. so you may want to either use selenium/a headless browser. also weird but if you skip the 6th element where the image_tag is None you end up with 24 results somehow. *still not the actual number of results.

Comment: Yep. I fixed it after realizing that. I used selenium with delays to scroll down and scrape the HTML after the images are loaded. A slow solution but atelast it works! 

Thanks a lot for helping!